# calculate days with gaps

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

table:

```
+-----------+--------------+------------+------------+
| RequestID | RequestStaus | StartDate  |  EndDate   |
+-----------+--------------+------------+------------+
|         1 | pending      | 9/1/2015   | 10/2/2015  |
|         1 | in progress  | 10/2/2015  | 10/20/2015 |
|         1 | completed    | 10/20/2015 | 11/3/2015  |
|         1 | reopened     | 11/3/2015  | null       |
|         2 | pending      | 9/5/2015   | 9/7/2015   |
|         2 | in progress  | 9/7/2015   | 9/25/2015  |
|         2 | completed    | 9/25/2015  | 10/7/2015  |
|         2 | reopened     | 10/10/2015 | 10/16/2015 |
|         2 | completed    | 10/16/2015 | null       |
+-----------+--------------+------------+------------+
```

I would like to calculate the days opened but exclude the days between completed and reopened. For example, RequestID 1, the days opened will be (11/3/2015 - 9/1/2015) + (GetDate() - 11/3/2015), for request 2, the total days will be (10/7/2015 - 9/5/2015) + ( 10/16/2015 - 10/10/2015).

The result I want will be something like:

```
+-----------+-------------------------------+
| RequestID |          DaysOpened           |
+-----------+-------------------------------+
|         1 | 63 + (getdate() - 11/3/2015)  |
|         2 | 38                            |
+-----------+-------------------------------+
```

How do I approach this problem? thank you!

Comment: You never finish your example -- what result do you expect for id 1 and 2?

Comment: As per your question, for RequestID 1, the datys should be (11/3/2015 - 9/1/2015) + (GetDate() - 11/3/2015). Isn't it?

Comment: @Dance-Henry, yes sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested. Works well. :)

Note: 
1) I suppose the `required result = (FirstCompleteEndDate - PendingStartDate)+(Sum of all the Reopen duration)`

2) So I used the self joins. Table `b` provides the exact `completed`  record which immediately follows the `in process` record for each `RequestID`. Table c provides `Sum of all the Reopen duration`.

```
--create tbl structure
create table #test (RequestID int, RequestStatus varchar(20), StartDate date, EndDate date)
go


--insert sample data
insert #test 
select 1,'pending','09/01/2015','10/2/2015'
union all
select 1,'in progress','10/2/2015','10/20/2015'
union all
select 1,'completed','10/20/2015','11/3/2015'
union all
select 1,'reopened','11/3/2015',null
union all
select 2,'pending','09/05/2015','9/7/2015'
union all
select 2,'in progress','09/07/2015','9/25/2015'
union all
select 2,'completed','9/25/2015','10/7/2015'
union all
select 2,'reopened','10/10/2015','10/16/2015'
union all
select 2, 'completed','10/16/2015','11/12/2015'
union all
select 2,'reopened','11/20/2015',null



select * from #test



--below is solution
select  a.RequestID, a.Startdate as [PendingStartDate], b.enddate as [FirstCompleteEndDate], c.startdate as [LatestReopenStartDate], 
        datediff(day,a.startdate,b.enddate)+c.ReopenDays as [days] from #test a
join (
    select *, row_number()over(partition by RequestID,RequestStatus order by StartDate) as rid from #test 
) as b
on a.RequestID = b.RequestID
join (
    select distinct RequestID, RequestStatus, max(StartDate)over(partition by RequestID,RequestStatus) as StartDate, 
            Sum(Case when enddate is null then datediff(day,startdate,getdate()) 
                  when enddate is not null then datediff(day,startdate,enddate) 
             end)over(partition by RequestID,RequestStatus) as [ReopenDays]
    from #test
    where RequestStatus = 'reopened'

) as c
on b.RequestID = c.RequestID
where   a.RequestStatus ='pending' and b.RequestStatus = 'completed' and b.rid = 1
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Got a question, what if I have multiple complete and reopen dates, I need to sum them up, how do I do that?

Comment: Like for example: 
2,'completed','9/25/2015','10/7/2015'; 2,'reopened','10/10/2015','10/16/2015';
2, 'completed','10/16/2015','11/12/2015'; 2,'reopened','11/20/2015',null    what do you want as a result

Comment: Yes, something like that, so in your example, I need to add getdate() - '11/20/2015' . I don't know how to make it dynamically since there could be multiple reopen and completes. Thank you sir!

Comment: @Meidi I already update the query. I have a hypothesis which I wrote in the front. Give it a try and let me posted. :)

Comment: I found some glitch in data when I run this query. There are times when people reopened and then they put a hold status, then they change status to "in progress",  and the complete. That caused the data become negative days :(

Comment: for example: 2,'in progress','6/16/16','6/16/16'
2,'completed', '6/16/16','6/16/16'
2,'reopen','6/16/16','6/16/16'
2, 'hold','6/16/16','8/1/16'
2,'in progress', '8/1/16','8/1/16'
2,'completed', '8/1/16',null
this should come out 0 days open isn't it? since (6/16/16 - 6/16/16) + (8/1/16 - 8/1/16 ) = 0

Comment: Come on dude, i do not have those information like "hold", could you please give all the details or just change the code accordingly. I think you can open another question with all the necessary info and the exact result which you want.